# NPM not installing devDependencies on bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: npm-install, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to setup my first Bitbucket pipeline which simply builds my application and deploys it to my FTP server using the following `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
image: node:6.9.4

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
    - step:
        script:
          - npm run build
          - node deploy.js
```

The issue lies in the `npm install` because when bitbucket tries to run the `npm run build` command it says that `rimraf` (a npm package) is not found. `rimraf` however is listed in my `devDependencies`, all regular `dependencies` in my `package.json` are downloaded correctly.

There is no global variable set by my so the `NODE_ENV` could not be it right?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. For me, the problem was that **the version of Node on my local development device was different from the version of Node in the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file**.

To fix it, I went into `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` and changed this line:

```yaml
image: node:10.15.3
```

to this:

```yaml
image: node:14.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with gulp.

Gulp was in devDependencies and also specified in package.json as script but still it said `npm ERR! missing script: gulp`

The documentation says to install it globally, so there might be a related issue with your package.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/javascript-node-js-with-bitbucket-pipelines-873891287.html